# Hibernate annotation for Map<String, List> or List<List>

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am new to hibernate, I have learnt how to annotate `Map<String, String>` or `Map<String, CustomObject>` or `List<CustomObject>` etc. However I could not find a way to annotate `Map<String, List>` or `List<List>`

E.g. The following is how I can annotate a `Map<CustomKey, CustomObject>` and it's working.

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass=PhoneNumber.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@MapKeyClass(NumberType.class)
@MapKeyColumn(name="type")
@CollectionTable(name="phones", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id"))
@Getter
@Setter
private Map<NumberType, PhoneNumber> phones;
```

and

```
@Embeddable
public class NumberType {
}
```

and

```
@Embeddable
public class PhoneNumber {
}
```

Now, my requirement is to annonate a property like `Map<CustomKey, List<CustomObject>>` and `Map<CustomKey, Map<AnotherCustomKey, CustomObject>>`

so my question: **Is it possible to do by Hibernate/JPA? Or do you achieve this kind of purpose differently in hibernate?**

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In general,** 
A Map represents a many-to-many relation and as a such be mapped by `@ManyToMany` annotation.
A List is a one-to-many or many-to-one relation, so that whould be `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToOne` annotation correspondingly.
Hibernate deals with entities and relations between them.

So the `Map` value type (`Map/List`) **in the example** should be represented by it own entity. E.g. `List<CustomObject>` would be `CustomObjectGroup`.